# What is the right tool to diff filecontents of a directory in OSX?

Tags: macos, diff

I know that I can use Git for some cases, but I still believe that there exists a simpler solution by default.

**Does there exists any tools by default in the newest OSX for the diff of filecontents in a directory?**

Answer (score 4):

You mean, like [`diff`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/diff.1.html)?

```
$ diff test1 test2
Only in test1: a
Only in test2: b
```

Comment: Is there any tool to compare filecontents for the same comparison, instead of filenames? Diff seems to check only the filenames.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to compare. Your question was a little vague. You can of course do a `for f in dir1/*; do diff "$f" dir2/"${f#dir1/}"; done` to compare each file from one directory with one of the same name in another. Maybe you could be more specific as to what you need to achieve.

Comment: @Masi So you are aware that `diff` does not only check filenames but is primarily used for diffing file content? Your original question only asked about directory contents. Have you tried using `diff` on files? What specific problem did you encounter or why didn't it work for you? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a recursive diff over an entire directory tree with

diff -r

An example:

```
echo content1 > x/test.txt
echo content2 > y/test.txt
diff -r x y
diff -r x/test.txt y/test.txt
1c1
< content1
---
> content2
```